# How do I enable Cython code-folding in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, cython, code-folding

Code-folding for Cython (.pyx) seems to be mostly not working in PyCharm Professional. The GUI shows some if/for loops as expandable with a `+` sign on the left-hand side. However, other loops and all function definitions are not expandable, either via the GUI or with keyboard shortcuts. PyCharm support pages indicate that code-folding is supported for Cython.

How do I enable full code-folding capabilities? Does it depend on the theme I am using (Dracula)? FWIW, I am on Ubuntu, using Gnome keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I don't think it is supported. See the relevant ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19546

Comment: Yup, sounds like it. Thanks for the link to the bug tracker.